# Displaying user information on an popover alert view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipopovercontroller

I am working on an app for a Cafe where users can "sign in" to their seats. 
Currently I am thinking of a way to present basic user information of seated people. What I am envisioning is to when the table gets tap, a square information box (pardon my primitive language) appears in the middle with the background being blurred out. I am hoping to have something flexible so that i can add tab and such to this so called box.

I have been looking at popover alert controllers and apparently there is limited information on them in regards to the iPhone. Is there a reason why popover view is not used for iPhones as compared to iPads? Moreover, is there a smarter UI to handle this or should i just segue to the next view when tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up two different concepts: Alerts vs View Controllers being displayed modally.

[Alerts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html) – as the name suggests – are used to bring something important to the attention of the user. They usually interupt the current flow.

View Controllers presented modally are similar to what you discribe: a new View Controller moves over the current one, and the current one is blacked out to put emphasis to the new one. As you rightly pointed out though, this is hardly used on iPhone: This is because iPhones historically have rather small screens, and scaling down a view controller leaves hardly any room for content.

View Controllers presented as [popovers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH5-SW1) is yet another thing: Here, you show the new view controller in a separate window that originates from a specific point in your UI.

[This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html) might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, popovers are iPad-only because iPhone screens are too small to make them effective. UIAlertController is a similar alternative, though it may  not lend itself to what you're trying to accomplish.

Segueing to a new view for the user information is definitely a solid option, or if you want to preserve the feeling of staying on the same view you can animate a custom view over top of your current view, often from the bottom in the style of a keyboard or the settings drawer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a Modally presented View Controller. For this, you will create the view you want to pop up in a separate view controller. Then, control-drag in a segue from the parent view to the Modal of type `Present Modally`. You can even get your blurriness by setting your Modal's background to clear and adding a `Visual Effect with Blur` to its view.

[image]

Now, give the segue an identifier in the right hand pane so you can call it programatically.

Comment: When i do that, the new view takes up the entirety of the initial view. Is there a way to resize the new view so that it only takes up a partial space of the old view?

Comment: You could pull a visual trick in storyboard by making the background totally transparent (or blur) and then making a colored box out of a UILabel to shroud your content.